# Wordpress redirection problem after moving to a new server?

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

I've created a site using wordpress and i moved that from localhost to new server.

The steps i've followed is just got backup of old db from localhost and uploaded them to the new server. Changed the WordPress address (URL) & Site address (URL) manually from phpmyadmin.

Moved all the files from localhost to the server

Changed the wp-config with the new server's db details.

Now i'm able to visit the admin panel of wordpress but not the site.

Its showing the following error,

> The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server
>   is redirecting the request for this
>   address in a way that will never
>   complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to
>   accept
>             cookies.

I think that this must some redirection problem..

My new .htaccess file under new server is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /veejata/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /veejata/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please post the entire question here as a courtesy to users of this site.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I did that.. :)

Comment: It was issue in the windows server with wordpress 3.1 so i installed the Permalink fix pack @ wordpress.org/extend/plugins/… .Now its working fine.. I've no issues linux server.. I've to dive into the thing to know that is happening in windows server...

Comment: Issued resolved by http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/ Installing this plugin fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself..

It was issue in the windows server with wordpress 3.1 so i installed the Permalink fix pack @ [wordpress.org/extend/plugins/… .](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/)

Now its working fine.. I've no issues linux server.. 
I've to dive into the thing to know why that is happening in windows server...

Answer (score 0):

Hi **@kvijayhari:**

You probably need to follow the instructions here about changing your Site URL:

- [Changing the Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_Site_URL)

For your convenience, so you don't have to click over to that site, here is probably what you need to do; add the following to your `/wp-config.php` file, replacing `http://example.com` with the URL of your website:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

Also , as the error says, delete your browser cookies and change your auth cookies in wp-config.php if you have them ( last part is not 100% necessary but it can force your browsers to use new cookies).